# Entity Framework Core SaveChanges causes error on Mac

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm currently trying to build an EF core project, but when I call db.SaveChanges() I get the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetModuleHandle assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Data.Common.SafeNativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(string)
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper..ctor () [0x00006] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.InOutOfProcHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x0000d] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions (System.String connectionString, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions previous) [0x00000] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup (Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey key, Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) [0x0003e] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set (Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey key) [0x00008] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) [0x0006b] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential credential) [0x00006] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <a1c8e16fd44948ee8c6a463f125e71f0>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(string)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection () [0x00006] in <5c775909c1cf40629fd2452310cf8cc1>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection () [0x0000a] in <5314a29febc14288a1bc53bf7b46d725>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateCommand (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, System.Guid commandId, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.DbCommandMethod commandMethod) [0x0005c] in <5314a29febc14288a1bc53bf7b46d725>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject) [0x00027] in <5314a29febc14288a1bc53bf7b46d725>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator[T].InitializeReader (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext _, System.Boolean result) [0x00050] in <5314a29febc14288a1bc53bf7b46d725>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult] (TState state, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] operation, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] verifySucceeded) [0x00011] in <5c775909c1cf40629fd2452310cf8cc1>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () [0x00193] in <5314a29febc14288a1bc53bf7b46d725>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs:104 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext)
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression query) [0x00075] in <a3dbe48366454fdbb51dfeeb0b5c4997>:0 
  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult] (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) [0x00000] in <a3dbe48366454fdbb51dfeeb0b5c4997>:0 
  at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[T] source) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-10/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs:729 
  at GenericEFIAPI.RTATenantsDatabaseHelper.convertTenant (System.String tenantId, GenericEFIAPI.configObject config, GenericEFIAPI.models.TenantDatabase db) [0x002d2] in /Users/jft/projects/GenericAPI/GenericEFIAPI/RTATenantsDatabaseHelper.cs:108 
  at GenericEFIAPI.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Main>b__0 (GenericEFIAPI.Program+Options o) [0x000c1] in /Users/jft/projects/GenericAPI/GenericEFIAPI/Program.cs:78 
  at CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.WithParsed[T] (CommandLine.ParserResult`1[T] result, System.Action`1[T] action) [0x00011] in <68c69d6559fd42bc897efd2a474dfda9>:0 
  at GenericEFIAPI.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00013] in /Users/jft/projects/GenericAPI/GenericEFIAPI/Program.cs:38
```

I've tried looking around on google for some help, but have come up empty so far... Anybody have any ideas?  I'm trying to connect to sql server and using DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer() for the underlying connection.

I'm currently getting my old windows laptop up and running to see if it is because I'm on a Mac or not, but I thought I would get this question out there in the mean time.

Comment: You need to check the connection string that entity is using.

Comment: How would any of those lead to an error to load a driver? The error literally is "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: GetModuleHandle assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)" - which at least in my eyes (not a mac person) indicates a not found assembly.

Comment: Yeah, and that's the rabbit hole that I got lead down.  But I'm going to double-check the connection string and make sure that it is right and that I can connect to that instance.

Comment: @jdweng just to confirm, I can connect and query against that connection string using just the regular SqlConnection class, so I highly doubt that is the issue, unless the format it is in needs to be different.

Comment: I think it is failing when the connection open is occurring and if the mdf file path is bad you are getting the exception.

Comment: If connection string is working SQL Client and not Entity then is is the mapping file that is bad.  So you need to refresh the mapping file.

Comment: @jdweng sorry for my ignorance, what mapping file are you talking about?  I need to dynamically generate sql connection strings and pass that in because each of our client dbs are individual databases.

Comment: When an Entity database is created c# classes are created and a mapping is create to link the classes to the tables in the database.  So there is an edmx file that contains the mapping.  A SQL Server can have multiple databases with different credentials.  The client database can be exactly the same structure so you c# classes can be the same.  Just the connection string  need to call out a different default database.

Answer (score 0):

Alright!  So I'm not 100% sure why my connection string is failing when passing it directly to the DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(connectionString), but if I create a SqlConnection object before that, and pass that as the parameter to UseSqlServer, it works.

So got a workaround, but not sure why the error happens when just passing the connection string.